# Not able to connect to a new MongoDB Community Edition installation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, macos

I have installed mongoDB via manual on [mongodb.com](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). 
In terminal I have checked the status and the database is running:

```
Name                  Status  User     Plist
mongodb-community     stopped          
mongodb-community@3.6 stopped          
mongodb-community@4.0 started vondramk /Users/vondramk/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.0.plist
```

Despite this, I try to connect (again via terminal) with `$ mongo` and it gives me this error:

> connection response contain error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-12-17T08:35:23.648+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2019-12-17T08:35:23.651+0100 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2019-12-17T08:35:23.651+0100 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Can anyone guide me on how can I resolve this issue?